# Slideshare api getting 'Failed API Validation' error response

Tags: api, linkedin-api, zoho, zoho-deluge

I have applied for slideshare API and i got the API and the secret. All i have did is a simple GET request to slideshare which gives me results with the help of a tag.

This is my deluge script which i have tried to call the url using the API.
As per the documentation, i have got the unix time stamp and SHA1 hash.

```
param = Map();
param.put("api_key","XYZ");
param.put("ts","1565085930");
param.put("hash","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
param.put("tag","cricket");
request = invokeurl
[
    url :"https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/get_slideshows_by_tag"
    type : GET
    parameters: param
];
info request;
```

This is the response error i get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <SlideShareServiceError> 
        <Message ID="1">Failed API validation</Message> 
   </SlideShareServiceError>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the API does not work with a **GET** request. Try the same using a POST request and it should work. The same failed with **POSTMAN** and it worked only after the request type was changed to **POST**.

```
param = Map();
head = Map();
param.put("api_key","XXXXXXXX");
param.put("ts",1577955246);
param.put("hash","b3f3f803XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8be21d");
param.put("tag","cricket");
request = invokeurl
[
    url :"https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/get_slideshows_by_tag"
    type : POST
    parameters: param
];
info request;
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Tag>
 <Name>cricket</Name>
 <Count>0</Count>
</Tag>
```